# NiFi : How to select the database tablename through the drop-down instead of entering it manually?

Tags: sql, apache-nifi, processor

I want a custom nifi processor that makes it easier for users to get database table names.

When connected to a database [set the Database Connection Pooling Service], how can I allow users to select the database table name through a drop-down instead of manually entering it?

As shown in the figure below, when I want to obtain the data of a table name from the database, I can manually fill in the desired database table name by setting the processor parameters (In the picture, what I need to fill in is the name of the data table "weather_raw").

After the database connection is configured, I want to provide all the data table names of the current database for users to choose from (Let users choose between "weather_raw" and "weather_filter", assuming that these two tables are all tables in the database). How would I go about this?

[image: figure about choose database tablename]

Comment: NiFi is a data ingestion tool and there are other better options to make your flow dynamic. I really wanted to understand - what's the use case for such a requirement?

Comment: It is possible, you'd have to look at existing NiFi processors code to see how they use drop down for config items. However, this sounds like a really bad idea and not what NiFi is intended for...

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde  Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to modify nifi so that it can be used by non programmers. Just like those who don't know database operations and get database tables. It is convenient for them to use graphical nifi to operate databases or other types of data. Yes, it's really a bad idea. But I want to implement a software that non programmers can process data. Are there any other good open source framework recommendations? thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @Sdairs Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to modify the nifi processors code as you said. Although it's a bad idea. I will answer this question when I have a way to achieve it. Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Let myself give a superficial solution. First of all, this question does not conform to the design logic of nifi.

Because when setting up a specific processor, you may not get the required database table (the database table may change all the time).

I considered using the parameter "allowablevalues in propertydescriptor class" corresponding to the drop-down list in the nifi source code, but this is immutable and shared by all processors. I also thought about adding a propertydescriptor property to display the list, but I feel it is too dangerous to modify the source code.

The rough implementation method I think of at present is to modify the front and back APIs. In order to meet the requirements of not modifying the nifi source code as much as possible. The front end opens the processor parameter setting interface every time, or sends a specific API to the back end after changing the server connection every time, and the back end makes regular requests and returns.

I saw nifi advanced UI on the official website. It can sending api in advanced UI.

However, this method may not take into account the possibility of conflicts with the source API, such as the sequence of sending APIs, or data processing in distributed situations.

If there are other methods, I will give them later. If you have better methods, I welcome discussion. Thanks for your attention.